# How to calculate Java garbage collection ratio using JMX counters?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jmx

I would like to measure "gc ratio percentage" with my JMX client from target JVMs (HotSpot & IBM JVMs). I can get following counters via JMX:

- JVM uptime (wall clock time)
- JVM process cpu time
- Number of cores
- Collection time per garbage collector

With these input counters, what is the best formula to calculate "gc ratio"?

I have tried formula:

```
collection_time / jvm_process_cpu_time * 100%
```

But in some cases collection time can be more than jvm process cpu time (>100% ratio), so obviously collection_time must be then wall clock time. So can I do calculation using formula:

```
collection_time / (jvm_process_cpu_time * nbr_of_cores) *100%
```

or just by:

```
collection_time / jvm_uptime *100%
```

I also found article ([Java: does GarbageCollectorMBean.getCollectionTime return pause time or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516168/java-does-garbagecollectormbean-getcollectiontime-return-pause-time-or-somethin)) where is described how to get collection cpu time instead of wall clock time, but after my tests it reports exactly the same collection time than `GarbageCollectorMXBean.getCollectionTime()`.

Br,
Jouni

Comment: What's the real problem that you're trying to solve? That should guide you. In any case, CPU time seems unlikely to be the right metric unless your application is constantly at 100% on all cores.

Comment: We need to add gc activity monitoring to our application's self-monitoring funtionality. We have tens of JVMs to be monitored and this should be active 24/7 also on customer installations, so JVM's GC logging parameters cannot be used.

Comment: In that case, `collection_time / uptime` is probably sufficient, as it gives you a sense for how often the GC is running. Anything else is almost certainly false precision.